# Can 1 inch unshielded wire attract interference current?

Tags: emi-filtering

In shielded EEG leads, the purpose is to resist capacitive coupling where interference current can couple to the high impedance electrode resulting in significant noise. I read "A typical interference current is of the order of 20 nA, which, given an interelectrode impedance of even 10 kΩ, yields an interference voltage of 200 μV, a magnitude capable of drowning the EEG signal being measured, which is normally between 10 and 100 μV (Aurlien et al., 2004)."

I'd like to know if an unshielded exposed wire measuring mere one inch can like in photo below can attract interference current? Or is there a minimum length where it can't attract capacitive coupling/interference current?

[image]

Comment: These wires ARE shielded, by the metal chassis. Not a problem.

Comment: The sides of the chassis are plastic. only the top,  bottom, front and back are metal. can it get through the plastic at sides?

Comment: @Justme you mentioned below even a ground wire attracted interference, but isnt if your put shield made of metal to ground away the interference? how does metal shield around wire differ to a ground wire?

Comment: @Jtl Assume your EEG device is battery operated, so it has no reference to any other potential. If you attach electrodes to me, they measure signal on one elecrode in reference to some other electrode. Assume I am a human, which means I am mostly a bag of conductive saltwater, and I go near an extension cord, where a conductor inside insulator has a sine wave of 150V amplitude, so my body also gets capacitively coupled with a few hundred millivolts, it adds to both the signal and reference. Since your battery operated device subtracts the reference from signal, you are left with signal.

Comment: Yes my eeg unit is entirely battery operated, so what is the use of shielded lead connected to ground??

Comment: compared to the above.. How about if the EEG is AC plugged in but it has galvanic isolation. Does the isolated ground float also or does it somehow reference to zero by interacting with the circuit ground and AC ground?

Comment: your explanation above is describing the operation of the differential amplifier where it  subtracts the reference from signal, what  has it got to do with ground having also attracted interference current and  my questions what is the purpose of shielded lead if the shield attracts interference current too. im confused by your explanation. pls elaborate tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it certainly **can** pick up interference.

There is no minimum length where a wire suddenly stops picking up noise/interference.

The length of the wire just determines how much interference it will pick up and what frequencies it will pick up.

Another thing is, if the 1 inch of wire will pick up an amount that is significant to your application, and even if it does, if the input front-end of the circuit will be able to filter it out or otherwise deal with it.

Comment: If the lead is shielded. Is a one foot shielded as good as a 10 foot shielded? meaning if its shielded, its the same whatver its length?

Comment: @Jtl unless there are no numbers/data about the cable or interference, we can't say anything. Except that shielded cable is just two conductors separated by an insulator, which means there will be more capacitance added for every inch of shielded cable.

Comment: Shielded means there is a metal mesh around wire connected to ground. A 2 conductor separated by insulator is just ordinary unshielded wire. no?

Comment: @Jtl The point was that there is capacitance between any two conductors separated by any insulator. Whether a conductor that has a shield conductor around it, or two conductors of unshielded wire. The coaxial/shielded cable may add more capacitance you expect.

Comment: @Jtl More like, repel. Shield will protect the sensitive signal from interference. Any added capacitance of the shield to the middle conductor carrying a weak small signal with high impedance will act as a low pass filter. But capacitance will also remove high frequency noise in addition to the signal. Much like having either a short cable or long cable between a guitar and amplifier to give a real world example, the long cable will sound more muffled and short cable will sound more crisp.

Comment: @Jtl The connectors are just metal in an insulator. Just like the wire. It is no different.

Comment: oh one more thing I forgot. can a long ground wire itself attract interference?

Comment: @Jtl Any wire could. It does not matter what the wire does in a circuit.

Comment: @Jtl The original question is answered. Please don't continue by editing in new but unrelated questions or asking them in the comments. If you have new questions about new subject, start a new question.

Comment: see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/705199/ground-in-battery-powered-device-interacting-with-capacitive-coupling