# Ground in battery powered device interacting with capacitive coupling

Tags: emi-filtering

If even the ground wire in a battery powered device especially biopotential measuring devices like EMG can attract interference current. Then what is the use of shielded leads that connects to ground for such device that measures biopotentials? The Shielded leads can really attract interference current?

For device with galvanic isolation, the ground is floating, so does it mean all biopotential measuring devices that use galvanic isolation can have the ground wire and shielded ground attracts interference current too?

Since the differential inputs V+ and V- is each deducted from the ground/reference, then what would be the effect on the output?