# Can 60Hz notch filter remove inteference current on input leads in high impedance electrodes?

Tags: filter

In a bioamplifier. Interference current on the leads can interact with the electrodes impedance giving rise to voltages at the differential input. My question is, can a 60Hz notch filter in the software remove it or is capacative coupling/interference current a separate phenomenon from the putpose of notch filters?

Comment: Most forms of power line interference are not a single sine wave, but many harmonics of the fundamental waveform.

Comment: you can notch filters only remove a single sine wave?

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of a notch filter. You might try looking into "comb filter" instead.

Comment: Is the target of  notch filter  the interference current interacting with high impedance at electrodes or is it from line interference ? what else

Comment: @Jtl Perhaps consider spending a little time reading though [TI's SBAA188 application report](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa188/sbaa188.pdf) and improve your question as you see fit, from there.

Answer (score 4):

As already said, the purpose of a notch filer is to remove a tight frequency range so it will in theory remove the interference.

However practically it might not be that simple. If you apply the filtering at the end of the acquisition, your signal might not be strong or precise enough to be usable. This depends on the type (strength) of biopotential your are sensing but in general the 60Hz noise is likely to be orders of magnitude stronger than the biopotential. Therefore the initial amplification is limited by the noise amplitude in order not to clip (exceed maximum range of amplifier output). You would typically pre-amplify the signal this way, then use a filter to remove the 60hz and then amplify the de-noised signal again, such that you can utilize the maximum dynamic range of the ADC at the end.

Some additional tips regarding 60Hz noise and bioamplifiers:

- The vast majority of the 60Hz noise is coupled to the electrode *leads* and the skin between the electrodes, not the electrodes themselves.
- You can use shielded/coaxial leads to significantly reduce the noise
  at the amplifier input.
- You can also use active electrodes, which drive the leads with low impedance, and therefore also eliminate a significant amount of the 60Hz noise.
- You can use what's known as a "right leg driver" to reduce the common-mode noise coupled on the skin between electrodes. This is old and well proven technology with many resources describing it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a 60 Hz notch filter will by definition remove or filter away anything that is 60 Hz.

Comment: Hi, no one answers my question here about ground attracting interference current (follow up of your own statement) so when you have time, kindly answer this tnx.   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/705199/ground-in-battery-powered-device-interacting-with-capacitive-coupling